# Why am I receiving a Uncaught TypeError from a property inside of my JSON/Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am receiving an  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined`
`farmID=Obj.photo[1].farm;` //<< error starts on this line

```
$.getJSON( url, function( Obj ) {

   weatherAndFlickrReport(Obj);
 });
```

I am not sure what to do, because it actually is a property inside of my JSON object. It is stopping the execution of my code.

[image: Snippet of the JSON data]

When I change the code to this:

```
    var url='https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/method=flickr.galleries.getPhotos&api_key=9c97a9b3a44149de735e3a738c7b82ed&gallery_id=72157665782409143&extras=original_format&format=json&jsoncallback=?';
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
   var myObj    = data.photos;
  weatherAndFlickrReport(data);

    if(data.stat != 'fail') {
      console.log("Some failure");
    }

});
```

I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

**Please help. These are the functions that the objects are being passed to:**

```
function flickrReport(Obj, yahooDate)
{
    var farmID="", serverID="",photoID="", origSecr="", format="", date=0;
    var photoUrl=""; 

    count++;
    console.log("flickReport count: "+count);
    console.log(" in the flickReport ");
    var myObj = JSON.stringify(Obj);
        console.log(myObj);

    farmID=Obj.photo[1].farm;
    serverID=Obj.photo[1].server;
    photoID=Obj.photo[1].id;
    farmID=Obj.photos.photo[1].farm;
    origSecr=Obj.photos.photo[1].originalsecret;
    format=Obj.photos.photo[1].originalformat;      photoUrl="https://farm"+farmID+".staticflickr.com/"+serverID+"/"+photoID+"_"+origSecr+"_o."+format;  
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+photoUrl+")";


    console.log(photoUrl);

bool=true;
console.log("The bool in flickr report is: "+bool);
    }

function weatherAndFlickrReport(jsonObj)
 { 

     // jsonObj= JSON.parse(jsonObj);
     console.log(jsonObj);
    var forecastArray=[], forecast=[];
    /*Calling flicker to breakdown JSON, sending date*/
    var myDate = new Date();
     var myDay = myDate.getDay();

    console.log("This is the day of the week: "+myDay);
```

-

```
        function inner(){ flickrReport(jsonObj, myDay);}

    if(bool===false)
    {          
     inner();

    }

    else if(getWoeid===true)
    {
            getWoeid=false;
          woeid=jsonObj.places.place.woeid;
        tempUrl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D"+woeid+"&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";
         var call =new callWeatherAndFlickr();
        call.RunCaLL(tempUrl);

    }

/* --- --- --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- */

 var iconCode =jsonObj.query.results.channel.item.condition.code;
var iconUrl = 'http://vibecityent.com/blacksota/SVG/weatherSVG/colorful/svg/'+iconCode+'.svg';
image.style.backgroundImage="url("+iconUrl+")";
    var mainTempNum = jsonObj.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
    var unit =   jsonObj.query.results.channel.units.tempurature;
    //  if(unit=="F"){$("#littleF").}
     var cityJSON = jsonObj.query.results.channel.location.city;
    var regionJSON =  jsonObj.query.results.channel.location.region;
     var countryJSON =  jsonObj.query.results.channel.location.country;
     var letterU = countryJSON.charAt(0); 
    var letterS = countryJSON.charAt(7);
    forecastArray = jsonObj.query.results.channel.item.forecast;
    debugger; 
    $("#barTitle").text(cityJSON+", "+regionJSON+" "+letterU+letterS);
    $("#iconText").text(jsonObj.query.results.channel.item.condition.text);
        $(".temp-gauge").text(mainTempNum);
```

-

```
     //debugger;
    for(var i=1;i<6;i++ )
    {
       var imgCode= forecastArray[i].code; 
            iconUrl =    'http://vibecityent.com/blacksota/SVG/weatherSVG/colorful/svg/'+imgCode+'.svg';

               var FcastDate =forecastArray[i].date.substring(0,6);
                 var day= forecastArray[i].day;
                 var hiTemp= forecastArray[i].high;
                 var lowTemp=forecastArray[i].low;
                 var txtStatus=forecastArray[i].text;       
               var wDate = day+", "+FcastDate;
               $("#locLine_"+i).text(wDate);
       $("#lowTemp_"+i).text(lowTemp+"°");
       $("#hiTemp_"+i).text(hiTemp+"°");
             var temp="LiCON_"+i;
       dropICONS=document.getElementById(temp);
        dropICONS.style.backgroundImage="url("+iconUrl+")";       
     }

    $(".location,#barTitle,#myImage,#iconText ,.temp-gauge,    #littleF").fadeIn(600);


}
```

This error will happen pretty much regardless of what I use: $.getJSON(), xhttp, $.ajax()

Here is a link to the flickr object from the server: [flickr Link](https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.galleries.getPhotos&api_key=9c97a9b3a44149de735e3a738c7b82ed&gallery_id=72157665782409143&extras=original_format&format=json&jsoncallback=Obj)

Link to app: [codepen link](http://codepen.io/NorrisWW/pen/XdoGdo?editors=0010)

Comment: Thats a javascript object, not JSON.

Comment: Where's the relevant code that throws the error? We can't guess what `weatherAndFlickrReport()` does

Comment: @charlietfl please see the updated code. Sorry about that